# Convert string to timestamp for Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a dataframe called `train`, he has the following schema :

```
root
|-- date_time: string (nullable = true)
|-- site_name: integer (nullable = true)
|-- posa_continent: integer (nullable = true)
```

I want to cast the `date_time`column to `timestamp`and create a new column with the `year` value extracted from the `date_time`column.

To be clear, I have the following dataframe :

```
+-------------------+---------+--------------+
|          date_time|site_name|posa_continent|
+-------------------+---------+--------------+
|2014-08-11 07:46:59|        2|             3|
|2014-08-11 08:22:12|        2|             3|
|2015-08-11 08:24:33|        2|             3|
|2016-08-09 18:05:16|        2|             3|
|2011-08-09 18:08:18|        2|             3|
|2009-08-09 18:13:12|        2|             3|
|2014-07-16 09:42:23|        2|             3|
+-------------------+---------+--------------+
```

I want to get the following dataframe :

```
+-------------------+---------+--------------+--------+
|          date_time|site_name|posa_continent|year    |
+-------------------+---------+--------------+--------+
|2014-08-11 07:46:59|        2|             3|2014    |
|2014-08-11 08:22:12|        2|             3|2014    |
|2015-08-11 08:24:33|        2|             3|2015    |
|2016-08-09 18:05:16|        2|             3|2016    |
|2011-08-09 18:08:18|        2|             3|2011    |
|2009-08-09 18:13:12|        2|             3|2009    |
|2014-07-16 09:42:23|        2|             3|2014    |
+-------------------+---------+--------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, if you want to *cast the date_timecolumn to timestampand create a new column with the year value* then do exactly that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.year

df
  .withColumn("date_time", $"date_time".cast("timestamp"))  // cast to timestamp
  .withColumn("year", year($"date_time"))  // add year column
```

Comment: @jackAKAkarthik This is not the same thing, and it looks your code fails with some streaming job.

Comment: It fails only after adding .withColumn to my dataframe.

Comment: So wat can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

You could map the dataframe to add the year at the end of each row:

```
df.map {
  case Row(col1: String, col2: Int, col3: Int) => (col1, col2, col3, DateTime.parse(col1, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).getYear)
}.toDF("date_time", "site_name", "posa_continent", "year").show()
```